# Stubbing a login for Google Oauth 2 with capybara automated testing

Tags: devise, automation, capybara, google-oauth

I am currently using Capybara to feature test an app in development at work. An issue I am running into is constantly logging in to the google oauth locks me out of my account for a while. Is there any way to stub a login to bypass the login process to speed up testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using `OmniAuth` to implement the OAuth handling there is a test mode you can enable which short circuits the actual logins - https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing and provides back whatever auth hashes you provide.

If you want to go at a higher level and just cut out the whole logging in step then you want to use the Devise integration test helpers - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests